# How to fix Error: Type FroalaEditorModule does not have 'ngModuleDef' property Using Froala Wysiwyg

Tags: angular, froala

I'm following the instructions at [Angular Froala WYSIWYG Editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-froala-wysiwyg) and I'm using angular version 8.3.26.

**app.nodule...**

```
import { FroalaViewModule, FroalaEditorModule } from 'angular-froala-wysiwyg'

imports: [  
    ...
    FroalaViewModule.forRoot(), FroalaEditorModule.forRoot()
],
```

I'm getting and error when I run the application:

```
Error: Type FroalaEditorModule does not have 'ngModuleDef' property.
```

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an open [BUG #441](https://github.com/froala/angular-froala-wysiwyg/issues/441) in editor's [Github repository](https://github.com/froala/angular-froala-wysiwyg) which does say this is an issue. One of the comment on the issue refers to a fix in [Open Pull request](https://github.com/froala/angular-froala-wysiwyg/pull/329) and suggests to use the build from the pull request as opposed to using standard npm package.

So you have 2 options. Either **upgrade to Angular 9** or **use build from the pull request** which I verified works fine!

In order to use build from pull request follow these steps:

1. Uninstall editor `npm uninstall angular-froala-wysiwyg --save`
2. Install package build from PR `npm i leo6104/angular-froala-wysiwyg#feat/ng-packagr-builds --save`
3. Add dependencies:

```
npm i froala-editor@3.0.5 --save 
npm i jasmine-core@>=3.5 --save
```

4. Run your app `ng serve`

[image]

Comment: @davy did you get a chance to take a look?

Comment: Hey Dipen, I tried and get an error - npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/leo6104/angular-froala-wysiwyg.gi

Comment: https://github.com/leo6104/angular-froala-wysiwyg.git You can install it with npm directly.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it is an issue with `Ivy` compilations, If you will turn it off everything will work fine.

**tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }
}
```

I would suggest you to go through below documents to get more about error and Ivy implementation:

[Angular Ivy](https://angular.io/guide/ivy)

[does not have 'ngModuleDef' property](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14594)

I am also new to this error, hope you find some help and hope this links help you.

Answer (score 0):

In this cases, *We want OP to reproduce the problem*. Never mind, So I list 3 minimal reproduction of [angular froala wysiwyg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-froala-wysiwyg) on Stackblitz. Please pay attention to their **patterns** and **dependency versions** which may solve your problem :

- [Stackblitz](https://angular-froala-wysiwyg.stackblitz.io) for Angular `^8.0.0` **with** *tsconfig.json* file,
  **multiple** domain
- [Stackblitz](https://angular-jafgm6.stackblitz.io) for Angular `^8.0.0` **without** *tsconfig.json*
  file, **single** domain
- [Stackblitz](https://angular-editor-wysiwyg.stackblitz.io) for Angular `^10.0.0` **without** *tsconfig.json*
  file, **single** domain